# How to manage Firefox addons after installing?

Tags: firefox-extensions, firefox

I'm a long-time Chrome user, converting to Firefox for group synergy. With Chrome, addons would be accessible from the top tool bar after installation. Firefox seems to make life difficult by hiding my installed addons?

I'm using Firefox 6.0.1; the specific addons I'm referring to include:

- [RESTClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/)
- [Twitter Address Bar Search](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/twitter-address-bar-search/)

From `Addons`, I can see the following:

[image]

The only way it seems I can access RESTClient is by changing the default layout for Firefox to display the `Menu Bar` (as opposed to the ribbon layout), such that I can access the `Tools` menu:

[image]

The Twitter Address Bar Search addon works in respect to searching Twitter, yet, one of the features, specifically the Twitter pinned tab, I cannot get working after closing. How can I re-instate this tab?

How do people manage their addons with Firefox?

Comment: i click the status bar and they fill up along the bottom - i'm not on firefox 6 but may still work

Comment: @mic84 - what status bar do you speak of?

Comment: from view menu two down, below toolbar

Comment: Not familiar with these addons (god why do ppl use twitter!)
Tried
Press CTRL + / or view - toolbars - addon bar
to bring up the addon tool bar at the bottom?

Comment: @mic84 - looks like right clicking on the top toolbar allows me to access the `Customize...` option from a context menu. From here I can easily add the icons for the addons I wish to launch (similar to Chrome). Having not shown the `Menu Bar` toolbar, I would never have found the icon to launch the addon.

Comment: You don't have to change layout to display `Menu Bar`. You just have to press `Alt` and it shows up.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Firefox actually has add-on bar, which is on the bottom of the browser. Check: http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/what-add-bar

Comment: yes; I guess coming from Chrome, and having spent  some time using FF now, I can comment that the add-on management in Chrome is much more streamlined.